# What is replacement for javafx.lang package of javafx 1.3 in javafx 2.1?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am converting my project from javafx 1.3 to javafx 2.1. But I have problem with `javafx.lang` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX 1.3 lang package content was split and moved to next places:

- Duration become `javafx.util.Duration`
- `javafx.lang.FX` methods are available from:

  - `javafx.application.Platform`
  - `javafx.application.Application`
  - and standard Java SE classes
- `Buildins` don't exist anymore. It's functionality can be substituted by Java SE.

Comment: Thanx Sergery.. I think this is not enough. Please give me more details. Because i am new in this field. Please help me....

Comment: If you have more specific question, please, ask it.